# Is it possible to accept a Sealed Trait with WebSocket.acceptOrResult in Play! scala

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I would like to use a kind of typed WebSocket with Play! Scala.

I would like that `WebSocket.acceptOrResult` accepts some commands like:

```
case class Message(msg: String)
case class CommandA(c: String)
```

etc.

I could use

```
WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue]
```

and try to convert them to the different case classes (commands) sequentially but I find it ugly.

A really better way to do it if possible would be to use a Sealed Trait

`ChatEvent` and extend the command classes i.e.

```
case class Message(msg: String) extends ChatEvent
case class CommandA(c: String) extends ChatEvent
```

But if I use it as following, the commands are not accepted:

```
  implicit val acommandFlowTransformer =
    MessageFlowTransformer.jsonMessageFlowTransformer[ChatEvent, ChatEvent]

  def openSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[ChatEvent, ChatEvent]
```

I have used

```
import julienrf.json.derived
implicit val chatEventMessage: Format[ChatEvent] = derived.oformat[ChatEvent]
```

that allows me to do:

```
Json.toJson(CommandA("aaa")).validate[ChatEvent] ---> JsSuccess[CommandA]
```

IMO the problem is that the format of `ChatEvent` leads to the class that extends `ChatEvent` and `acceptOrResult` is waiting for a `ChatEvent`.

Maybe the solution would be to use something like:

```
def openClientSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[_ :< ChatEvent, _ :< ChatEvent]
```

But I don't find how to make it compile.